# Selenium - screenshot images taken by headless server are mangled

Tags: python, selenium, webpage-screenshot, pyvirtualdisplay

I am using selenium webdriver (Python version) to take images of a web page after it loads.  When I go to a page and save an image using a python script on my local computer, it looks fine.  However, I am running the script on a server and there the screenshots are mangled- the edge might be cut off with text missing, banners on the right side might be pushed to the bottom in a jumbled fashion, etc.  I even tried maximizing the window

```
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(4)
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
```

On the server, I cannot load firefox in a headed version and must manually start/stop the display in my script before/after running selenium

```
from pyvirtualdisplay.xvnc import XvncDisplay
display = XvncDisplay(rfbport='####')
display.start()
```

So I'm thinking this might have to do with the settings of my display.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?  Thanks

Comment: Do you only have Xvnc installed or do you also have Xvfb?

Comment: Just Xvnc on the server

Answer (score 0):

Try chomium + chromedriver instead. It works for me, even though I didn't have the problem you describe. Just an idea.

Download chromedriver to /usr/local/bin https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads and don't forget `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

I used this blog post: http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.cz/2011/07/python-taking-browser-screenshots-with.html